# SceneKit overlay SKScene has no children when receiving a notification?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, scenekit

This seems like a huge glitch in my opinion.

I have an SKScene overlaying a SceneKit scene. In my app, a method is called to update progress on a "progress bar" (really just an `SKShapeNode` with a really low height). This method is called `updateSaveDataNotification` and takes an `NSNotification`. I called `[self childNodeWithName:]` to access a child node. **The problem is, when it's called, `self` has no children.** Even though it really has three children.

I'm changing my code so they're variables in the implementation so I can animate their scale that way, but why would this behavior even exist? Why would `self` have zero children in this instance?

---

**EDIT**: the progress bar is simply an `SKShapeNode`. Here's the code I used:

```
@implementation {
    SKShapeNode *progressBar;
    float progress;
}
…
-(void)load {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self name:@"anyName" selector:@selector(rcvNotification:) object:nil];
    progress = 0.0;
    …
    progressBar = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithRectOfSize:CGSizeMake(self.size.width * 0.9, 2)
    progressBar.xScale = 0;
    progressBar.alpha = 0;
    progressBar.fillColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    progressBar.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    progressBar.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height * 0.1);
    progressBar.name = @"progressBar";

    …

    [self addChild:progressBar]

    [progressBar runAction:[SKAction fadeAlphaTo:1 duration:1]];

}

// The notification has one KVP in its user info dictionary. This is "someKey."
// "someKey"'s float value is added to "progress."

-(void)rcvNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
    progress += [[notification.userData valueForKey:@"someKey"] floatValue];
    // [self updateUI];
    // note: if I call updateUI like that, self will have zero children regardless of whether or not it actually has more.
    // a remedy:
    [self runAction:[SKAction waitForDuration:0] completion:^{
        [self updateUI];
    }];
}

-(void)updateUI {
    NSLog(@"count of children: %lu", self.children.count);
    [progressBar runAction:[SKAction scaleXTo:progress duration:0.5] completion:
        // code to run when finished animating change
        // also logic for reaching 100% progress.
    }];
}
```

My predicament was, for a solid hour, not being able to re-scale that progress bar. I figured out `self` temporarily had 0 children, so I made it run a 0-second animation. I want to figure out why this odd behavior occurs.

Comment: Could you post code related to the 'progress bar's' creation?

Comment: Maybe moving the creation code from `- ()load` to `- ()init` could solve it